# kendo ui widget doesn't work in partial view after post-back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I load a partial view into kendo-ui window widget via jquery ajax , and no problem ,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     return PartialView("_Create");
}

public ActionResult Create(CreateObjectViewModel viewModel)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        //Persist  to database ...
       return Json(new {success=true});
     }
     return PartialView("_Create",viewModel);
}
```

All kendo ui widgets works fine , after submitting the form , client-side validation works fine too .

But if there is a server side validation error , I will return modelstate to the partial view and the view shows the errors .

In this case all my widget loose their functionality and do not work ,

here is how i submit the form in partial view :

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
     @* all kendo ui widget and form element *@
     <input type="submit" id="insert" onclick(submitForm(this.id)" value="insert" />
    }
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(documet).ready(function(){
       rebindvalidation();
    }

    function rebindValidation(){
       var form =$('form');
       form.removeData('validator');
       form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
       $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    }

    function submitForm(e){
       $('form').submit(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url:this.action,
         type:this.method,
         data:$(this).serialize(),
         success:function(result){
           if(result.success){
              $("#window").data('kendoWindow').close()
           }else{
             $('form').html(result);
             rebindValidation();
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

When I say it loose their functionality , Imagin the the multiselect widget behave just like a normal textbox , while it work at first load till not submitted to the controller:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiselectFor(p=>p.PartyIds)
.Name("PartyIds").DataTextField("Title").DataValueField("Id")
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.DataSource(s=>s.read(r=>r.Action("SearchAllPerson","Party"))
.Data("getPartyIdsData")
s.ServerFiltering(true))
```

I'm wondering how could I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake , In partial view after postback  , I set the result to the form element , while It's correct to set to the window .

By another word instead of

```
else{
     $('form').html(result);
     rebindValidation();
}
```

would be correct to write like this :

```
else{
     $('#window').html(result);
     rebindValidation();
}
```